# Uncaught TypeError: addEventListener not working when calling external function instead of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, typeerror, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

I'm new on JavaScript, trying to understand how to use built-in `addEventListener` method.

When I call an *anonymous function* via `addEventListener` for a specific event, there is no problem, everything is working and fine. However, When I call an external function for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, I get "`Uncaught TypeError`"

A) Working Example (anonymous function):

```
myBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';} );
myBtn.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';} );
```

B) Problem (external function):

```
myBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBackground(this, 'yellow') );
myBtn.addEventListener("mouseout", changeBackground(this, 'blue') );
```

To make it clear, check this out:

Full Demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Dom Event Listener Example #02</h1>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="myBtn1">Button 1</button><br>
        <button type="button" id="myBtn2">Button 2</button><br>
        <script>
        "use strict";
        
        var myBtn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
        var myBtn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
        
        //working scenario : anonymous function used
        myBtn1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';} );
        myBtn1.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';} );
        
        // PROBLEM here, calling exteral function not working
        myBtn2.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBackground(this, 'yellow') );
        myBtn2.addEventListener("mouseout", changeBackground(this, 'blue') );
        
        // external function, same functionality with anonymous function used above
        function changeBackground(elem, col) {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = col;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you mouse over the **Button 1** the *backgroundColor* parameter is togging between yellow and blue thus, `mouseover` and `mouseout` is working fine with this. Added event to the **Button 1** using *anonymous* function.

Although the *external* and *anonymous* functionality is same, when you move the *mouse in* and *out* over the **Button 2**, no change on **backgroundColor** of the Button 2 and console outputs the error below;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Why calling anonymous and external function behaves differently even their functionality is exactly the same? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> myBtn2.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBackground(this, 'yellow') );
> ```

You are calling `changeBackground(this, 'yellow')` **immediately** and trying to use its *return value* as the event listener function.

Wrap it in an anonymous function as you did previously (or generate the function using [the `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)).